How to modify and repackage squashfs in Ubuntu 24.04
How can I modify the official Ubuntu 24.04 server ISO to include additional packages by extracting and repackaging the squashfs files? In Ubuntu 20.04, I successfully repackaged the squashfs and updated the md5 file. However, Ubuntu 24.04 includes several squashfs files:
filesystem.manifest
filesystem.size
initrd
install-sources.yaml
ubuntu-server-minimal.manifest
ubuntu-server-minimal.size
ubuntu-server-minimal.squashfs
ubuntu-server-minimal.squashfs.gpg
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.manifest
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.size
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.squashfs
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.squashfs.gpg
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.manifest
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.size
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.squashfs
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.squashfs.gpg
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.manifest
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.size
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.squashfs
ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.squashfs.gpg

Which of these files need to be modified to ensure the ISO is installable correctly? My goal is to reduce installation time during an offline, automated installation by including these packages directly in the ISO (assuming this is possible)?
